# How to configure RequireJS (require.config()) with jasmine-node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, requirejs, jasmine

I have an init file that provides a function that bootstraps RequireJS via `require.config()`. The configuration ends up looking something (mostly) like this:

```
...

config =
    baseUrl: sysDir + 'lib/'
    paths:
        app: appDir + 'lib/'
        dep: sysDir + 'vendor/'
    deps: [
        'dep/underscore/underscore.min'
        'dep/jquery/jquery.min'
    ]

require.config config
```

This file is used in the browser and I want to use it in node too. I was trying to do the same thing in a helper but I'm not having much luck. Due to the way specs are ran in a new VM context, I'm not really sure what to do and there's no obvious way to pass jasmine-node your RequireJS config.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to kinda work by putting the require config into a spec_helper.js at the root of my specs directory:

```
define = require('requirejs');

(function () {
    var baseUrl = __dirname + '/../smoke'
    console.log('Configuring requirejs with baseurl: ' + baseUrl)

    define.config({
        'nodeRequire': global.require,
        'baseUrl': baseUrl
    });
})();
```

Not sure if that will really solve your problem or not.

Comment: As I said I've already tried that and it doesn't work because each spec is being ran in a new VM context.

Answer (score 0):

jasmine-node provides a sample project for requirejs: https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node#requirejs

if you call your tests like `> jasmine-node --runWithRequireJs --requireJsSetup tests/requirejs-setup.js tests`, you can add your configuration settings in the requirejs-setup - file.

nevertheless i've had a problem with the baseUrl-setting. in the requirejs-wrapper-template.js the baseUrl is manipulated and set relative to the current executed test file, which you can see here:

```
if(alteredConfig.baseUrl){
    var base = baseUrl.replace(/\\/g, '/'),
        splitUrl = alteredConfig.baseUrl.replace(/\\/g, '/').split('/'),
        index = 0;

    for(; index < splitUrl.length; index++){
        if(splitUrl[index] === '..') {
            base = path.dirname(base);
        } else {
            base += '/' + splitUrl[index];
        }
    }

    alteredConfig.baseUrl = base;
}
```

this leads to problems with defined paths from my requirejs config. so i simply commented out this code block. and now it works very well for me.